# How to create excel file in sharepoint from java?

Tags: java, excel, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to programmatically create an excel document and add it to the Sharepoint list. I didn't find any java libraries to create Excel files programmatically and works with SharePoint. I'm using graph-API to access the SharePoint documents.
Is there any way to do this and what's the best way to do it or even start researching about it?